# nslookup weird behavior in 2 pods on the same node in kubernetes

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes

I have 2 containers running in the same namespace.

- in-pod dns of the pod **xwing** does not resolving host name but will resolve FQDN
- **but** in-pod dns of the pod **utils** resolve it properly.

```bash
✗  kgpo  
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
deathstar-7848d6c4d5-g248j   1/1     Running   0          15m
deathstar-7848d6c4d5-qnsp8   1/1     Running   0          15m
tiefighter                   1/1     Running   0          15m
utils                        1/1     Running   0          11m
xwing                        1/1     Running   0          15m

➜ kgsvc         
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
deathstar    ClusterIP   172.20.41.112   <none>        80/TCP    15m
kubernetes   ClusterIP   172.20.0.1      <none>        443/TCP   46d

➜ k ice image               
PODNAME                     CONTAINER  PULL    IMAGE                          TAG
deathstar-7848d6c4d5-g248j  deathstar  Always  docker.io/cilium/starwars      -
deathstar-7848d6c4d5-qnsp8  deathstar  Always  docker.io/cilium/starwars      -
tiefighter                  spaceship  Always  docker.io/tgraf/netperf        -
utils                       utils      Always  saritasallc/network-multitool  -
xwing                       spaceship  Always  docker.io/tgraf/netperf        -
```

the following pods:

- **xwing** `(docker.io/tgraf/netperf)` and
- **utils** `(saritasallc/network-multitool)`

pods show the same `/etc/resolv.conf` values, yet they behave differently for `nslookup` query.

```bash
➜ kex xwing -- cat /etc/resolv.conf  
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local ec2.internal
nameserver 172.20.0.10
options ndots:5

➜ kex utils -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local ec2.internal
nameserver 172.20.0.10
options ndots:5
```

and **utils pod** can query service name **deathstar** but **xwing pod** can't. Only by FQDN of the service:

```bash
➜ kex utils -- nslookup deathstar  
Server:     172.20.0.10
Address:    172.20.0.10#53

Name:   deathstar.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 172.20.41.112

➜ kex xwing -- nslookup deathstar
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

➜ kex xwing -- nslookup deathstar.default.svc.cluster.local
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve
nslookup: can't resolve 'deathstar': Name does not resolve
command terminated with exit code 1

Name:      deathstar.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 172.20.41.112 deathstar.default.svc.cluster.loca
```

both pods are running on the same eks node.

After enabling logs in coredns I see this:

```bash
// kex utils -- nslookup deathstar (success)
[INFO] 10.120.133.213:45918 - 30670 "A IN deathstar.default.svc.cluster.local. udp 53 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 104 0.000298996s
[INFO] 10.120.133.213:45293 - 18650 "AAAA IN deathstar.default.svc.cluster.local. udp 53 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 146 0.000405998s

// kex xwing -- nslookup deathstar (failure)
[INFO] 10.120.134.84:32840 - 45185 "AAAA IN deathstar. udp 27 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 102 0.003295317s
[INFO] 10.120.134.84:32840 - 44875 "A IN deathstar. udp 27 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 102 0.003334905s
```

Comment: That got my attention. The domain suffix is loca, it is maybe typo moreover as if a domain name should not be in the address line.
`Address 1: 172.20.41.112 deathstar.default.svc.cluster.loca`

Comment: I am confused. you say it can resolve via FQDN, but in your 2nd query from xwing, it does NOT resolve the FQDN. It says it exited with code 1, then below you do have a resolution with what looks like a typo. Is this a typo from you pasting it here or does it really show that in the output? also, maybe edit your post with the correct outputs (as in NS lookup on xwing is not consistent with output of NSlookup done on util)